# How to Create a Timebased trigger using onEdit trigger Event?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup a timebased tigger with `onEdit` event. my current script is working succefully and creating the trigger as I want, But after few second trigger get disabled, Can anyone tell me how to rectify this?

```
function createnew(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  var r = e.range.getRow();
  var vl = e.value;
  var tm = sh.getRange(2, c).getValue();
  if (tm == '1 Minute') {
    var tr = ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyCells1')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
  }
}
```

[image: This Is result I get after setting up the trigger]

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Comment: The way you wrote this, every time the spreadsheet is edited and the cell `2, c` from the `Sheet1` has the value `1 Minute`, a new time-driven trigger will be installed. This way, it's likely that you will soon end up with many time-driven triggers, each of them firing `copyCells1` every minute. I don't think this is a good idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: hi, It's deleting old triggers and creating the new one.

Comment: `It's deleting old triggers` I don't see that in your code. Can you provide the related code? In any case, what's the point of continually deleting and creating time-driven triggers?

Comment: Here is the trigger deleting script
`code`
`function settrigger(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  

  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
  Logger.log(triggers[i].getEventType())
   
    if(triggers[i].getEventType() != "ON_EDIT"){
            
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i])
    }
   
  }
`

Comment: Is this function `settrigger` getting called as part of your `onEdit` function? Also, what's the point of deleting and creating the same trigger every time there is an edit to cell `2,c` with value `1 Minute`? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: yes, it's part of onEdit functions, and the reason for this is i with edit trigger I need to change the time trigger's frequency based on a Cell value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Triggers are deleted and recreated without errors. You are calling `settrigger` before `createnew`, right?